# React-Redux: How to add each item from array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

**My Current implementation of dispatch**

I have tried to dispatch items by mapping but sometimes Redux gives an undefined error so I want to try a better way in the reducer.

```
const dispatch = useDispatch()
const mapCheck =  [
    "Math",
    "Spanish",
    "Clean garden",
]

mapCheck.map(c=>dispatch(createCustomList(c.val)))
```

**What I am trying to do**

I am trying to get each individual Item from an array to dispatch but I am getting this output
I have a todo list in which I dispatch an array as shown below:

**My Reducer**

```
import { CUSTOM_LIST } from "../actions/shoppingList";

const initialState = { 
    myCustomItems: []
};

const ToDoReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case CUSTOM_LIST:
            const customList = { id: Date.now(),val: action.custom.custom};

            const custom = state.myCustomItems.concat(customList);

            const existingCustomItem = state.myCustomItems.findIndex(
                item => item.val === action.custom.custom
            );
            if (existingCustomItem >= 0) {
                return {...state, myCustomItems: state.myCustomItems}
            } else {
                return {...state,myCustomItems: custom};
            }
        default:
            return state;
    }
};

export default ToDoReducer;
```

**Desired Output**

How do I map each item and add them with an id as shown below in the desired output. Don't worry about the id that is just `Date.now()`

desired output:

```
const DesiredOutput = [{
        "id": "qm6a67ci",
        "val": "Math",
    },
    {
        "id": "qm6a62ci",
        "val": "Spanish",
    },
    {
        "id": "rkrkmroepe",
        "val": "Clean garden",
    }
]
```

Comment: is it your question: how to get DesiredOutput array from mapCheck array ?

Comment: No my question is a better way to map each item in an array from the reducer itself instead of doing it while dispatching

Answer (score 2):

Please use the below code. Hope it will fix your issue.

```
import { CUSTOM_LIST } from "../actions/shoppingList";

const initialState = { 
    myCustomItems: []
};

const ToDoReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case CUSTOM_LIST:
            const customList = { id: Date.now(),val: action.custom.custom};

            const existingCustomItem = state.myCustomItems.findIndex(
                item => item.val === action.custom.custom
            );
            if (existingCustomItem > -1) {
                return {...state, myCustomItems: state.myCustomItems}
            } else {
                return {...state,myCustomItems: [...state.myCustomItems,customList ]};
            }
        default:
            return state;
    }
};

export default ToDoReducer;
```

OR second way you can do is, instead of dispatching multiple actions you can dispatch a single action

The below code will remove duplicated from the array so you don't have to put a condition in your reducer

```
const dispatch = useDispatch()
const mapCheck =  [
    "Math",
    "Spanish",
    "Clean garden",
]

dispatch(createCustomList[...new Set(mapCheck)]))
```

Reducer file

```
import { CUSTOM_LIST } from "../actions/shoppingList";

const initialState = {
  myCustomItems: [],
};

const ToDoReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case CUSTOM_LIST:
      return {
        ...state,
        myCustomItems: action.customList.map((val) => ({
          id: Date.now(),
          val,
        })),
      };

    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export default ToDoReducer;
```